# Installed PHP module and restarted nginx but but PHP configuration isn't updating?

Tags: php

Okay, I'm on CentOS 5.3 and I'm running an nginx/php/mysql server stack with FastCGI. One of my Twitter apps requires PHP to connect to the Twitter API, which uses OAuth. So I installed the OAuth module with PECL and confirmed that oauth.so was compiled in /usr/lib/php/modules and extension=oauth.so was added in PHP.ini. However, when I try to access the PHP file I get a fatal error, the OAuth class is not found. So I checked phpinfo() and the PHP.ini file hasn't been reloaded apparently.

So, how do I force PHP with FastCGI to update its configuration without restarting the server?

Answer (score 0):

Php rereads its configuration on every request. You can check it by changing any var in php .ini ( like max mem )  and then see update in phpinfo.

can use your module in list of lodaded .so files in phpinfo?

Comment: I found the problem, it was loading the .ini file but for some reason the Oauth.so was failing silently because it was missing a dependency. It installed fine however, which was weird. Anyway, the solution was installing the curl-devel package.

Answer (score 0):

How do you invoke PHP? If you're by chance are using [PHP-FPM](http://php-fpm.org/), you might need to stop and start it again (at least this applied to older versions, not sure if this is still the case).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution was installing the curl-devel package... The module was failing to load (silently...).